# Unlist a list file to multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a R list with 72 elements. How I unlist this file to 72 single dataframes with the name of each element?

Here is an example:

```
L <- list(data.frame(matrix(1:4,2,2)),
          data.frame(matrix(9:12,2,2)),
          data.frame(matrix(5:8,2,2)))
names(L)<-c("a","b","c")
```

How can I get three dataframes, a,b,and c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `assign` to the global environment within an `lapply`. Note I have wrapped the call in `invisible` to avoid printing the output to the console.

```
invisible(lapply(names(L),function(x) assign(x,L[[x]],.GlobalEnv)))
ls()
[1] "a" "b" "c" "L"
a
  X1 X2
1  1  3
2  2  4
```

However, while the elements are in the list, they might be easier to work with, using `lapply` for example.

Answer (score 8):

There's a function for that...

```
list2env( L , .GlobalEnv )
```

But like James said, you need to have a good reason for *not wanting* to keep them in a list. It's much easier to work with lists than 72 separate `data.frame`s!. What are you trying to do.

Comment: I always forget about this and have seen it several times +1.

Comment: That's a good one to know +1

Comment: Thank you, Janmes and Simon. They're much helpful. I created this list for myself, but my colleagues sometime use some of the single files. So, I share it with them.

Answer (score 2):

This came to mind but James had already posted a better answer (essentially mine is the same but less cool) and then Simon and even better.  Just for completeness I'll throw it up but heed their warnings:

```
for (i in seq_along(L)) {
    assign(names(L)[i], L[[i]], .GlobalEnv)
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on Konrad's response I just realized you can do:

```
for (i in names(L)) {
    assign(i, L[[i]], .GlobalEnv)
}
```

I didn't know `for` loops could use non indices. Cool.

Comment: Why do you iterate over the indices rather than the names? You never need the indices.

Comment: @Knonrad I agree completely this was, as I said, what came to mind but also acknowledge it's by far the weakest solution here, though to iterate over the names (as far as I understand what you're saying) requires `lapply` not a `for` loop.

Comment: @Simon see my edit, I just realized that.

Comment: For completeness’ sake, `for` doesn’t iterate over indices *or* names. It simply iterates over values. `for (x in letters)` for instance iterates over the values of `letters`. Of course `seq_along(foo)` is just any other collection which can be iterated over, and so is `names(foo)` – so you can iterate over either. but unlike in languages like C, R has no bias at all towards iterating over indices, and in fact it’s quite rarely (= almost never) needed.