# How can I split large data.frame into smaller ones without using a loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe (20k rows) The dataframe basically contains a date / timestamp some text and a delta between the first timestamp and subsequent time stamps.

```
                date   text time.diff
1 2016-03-09 15:50:07 Text 1     0.000
2 2016-03-09 15:50:10 Text 2     2.808
3 2016-03-09 15:50:17 Text 3    10.128
4 2016-03-09 15:50:53 Text 4    45.952
5 2016-03-09 21:26:15 Text 5    65.053
```

I'd like to be able to split this dataframe into smaller chunks based on values contained in time.diff (say into chunks of 60 seconds). So for example, splitting into two using subset can be done like so, but if I have a much larger frame, I will end up writing 1000's lines of code!

I could also create a loop to iterate through a much larger dataframe and accomplish this task, but I know that using loops in R is rather slow.

So I'm wondering what approach I can take to split the larger frame into many smaller frames in a way that doesn't use a loop and can also increment smaller dataframe names e.g. df.sub.1, df.sub.2 ... df.sub.3

```
# Split into two frames based on matched criteria
df.split1 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff <= 60)
df.split2 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff > 60)

> df.split1
                 date   text time.diff
1 2016-03-09 15:50:07 Text 1     0.000
2 2016-03-09 15:50:10 Text 2     2.808
3 2016-03-09 15:50:17 Text 3    10.128
4 2016-03-09 15:50:53 Text 4    45.952
> df.split2
                 date   text time.diff
5 2016-03-09 21:26:15 Text 5    65.053
6 2016-03-09 21:26:20 Text 6    85.110
```

I've included some sample code to create the first six lines which hopefully should be enough for folks to suggest a way forward here.

```
# Create Data
date <- c("2016-03-09 15:50:07", "2016-03-09 15:50:10", "2016-03-09 15:50:17" ,
      "2016-03-09 15:50:53", "2016-03-09 21:26:15", "2016-03-09 21:26:20")
text <- c("Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6")
time.diff <- c(0, 2.808, 10.128, 45.952, 65.053, 85.110)
df.tosplit <- data.frame(date, text, time.diff)
```

Comment: If you have 3 or more splits, what is the condition?  Here you showed `>=60` and `<60`.

Comment: take a look at `split`... and `cut`

Comment: Well if i wanted to split every 60 seconds the condition would be like so: df.split1 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff <= 60)
df.split2 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff > 60 && <= 120)
df.split3 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff > 120 && <= 180)

and so on....

Comment: use `cut` on your time.diff variable with needed breaks to create a factor that you can then use in `split` to split your data.frame

Comment: something like `l1 <- split(df.tosplit, cut(strptime(df.tosplit$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'min'));final_list <- l1[sapply(l1, function(i) dim(i)[1]) > 0]` maybe?

Comment: Sotos this did work well. Many thanks you should add this code as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `split()`:

```
split(df, paste0("df.split", df$time.diff %/% 60))

$df.split0
                  dat   text time.diff
1 2016-03-09 15:50:07 Text 1     0.000
2 2016-03-09 15:50:10 Text 2     2.808
3 2016-03-09 15:50:17 Text 3    10.128
4 2016-03-09 15:50:53 Text 4    45.952

$df.split1
                  dat   text time.diff
5 2016-03-09 21:26:15 Text 5    65.053
6 2016-03-09 21:26:20 Text 6    85.110
```

Exotic way (see the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023053)):

`list2env(split(df, paste0("df.split", df$time.diff %/% 60)), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: utubun this is a really elegant solution thanks very much for this, I also read the exotic way post too. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a loop for each case, creating a sequence with the 60 second condition as an index will enable split points.

```
indx <- cut(df.tosplit$time.diff, 
            c(seq(0, max(df.tosplit$time.diff), by=60),Inf), 
            right=FALSE)
split(df.tosplit, indx)
# $`[0,60)`
#                  date   text time.diff
# 1 2016-03-09 15:50:07 Text 1     0.000
# 2 2016-03-09 15:50:10 Text 2     2.808
# 3 2016-03-09 15:50:17 Text 3    10.128
# 4 2016-03-09 15:50:53 Text 4    45.952
# 
# $`[60,Inf)`
#                  date   text time.diff
# 5 2016-03-09 21:26:15 Text 5    65.053
# 6 2016-03-09 21:26:20 Text 6    85.110
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre, this is similar (but different to the solution by Sotos) I think both generate a list which i can access using an element number as required.

Comment: @Sotos did not split on the `time.diff` column. You state in your question `"I'd like to be able to split this dataframe into smaller chunks based on values contained in time.diff "`

Comment: You also illustrate the same logic in the comments `subset(df.tosplit, time.diff <= 60) df.split2 <- subset(df.tosplit, time.diff > 60 && <= 120)`.